# Scheme Syntax Help: Using a function that I have defined in another program

Tags: function, syntax, scheme, subset-sum

I have created two functions to help me solve my [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). I seem to be getting an error though. It tells me that I am passing two arguments to `list-sum`. I've been fooling around with this program for several hours now. I was wondering if anyone could spot the problem.

This is my `list-sum`:

```
(define list-sum 
  (lambda(lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) 0)
      ((pair? (car lst))
       (+(list-sum (car lst)) (list-sum (cdr lst))))
      (else
       (+ (car lst) (list-sum (cdr lst)))))))
```

This is my function that uses `list-sum`:

```
(define ssum
  (lambda (n l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) #f)
      ((=(-(- n (car l))(list-sum l)) 0) l)
      ((ssum (cons (car l)) (cdr (cdr l))))
      (else (ssum n (cdr l))))))
```

It tells me that I have called "compound-procedure #(number) ssum" with one argument and that it requires two arguments. I am passing it as `(ssum 8 (list 1 3 5 7))`.

My questions are:

1. Have I set up my functions correctly?
2. Is there an easier method of summing
   the numbers of a list inside my `ssum`?
3. I am also very new to Scheme. If you see 
   an obvious way of shortening the code, 
   please feel free to correct me.

Comment: You do call it with only one argument, which is `(cons (car l) (cdr(cdr l)))`.

Comment: Answering the question is better than editing the code. I tried to figure out whats wrong with the program and saw your comment ... later.

Comment: Thanks guys.I felt kind of silly after such an easy fix. The recursion is hurting my brain(haha). Thank you for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to try [racket](http://racket-lang.org/), its IDE has this awesome debugger that only the [ODB](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/) could claim being better.

I didn't dig too deep in how your code is supposed to work, because there are actually several errors in the `((ssum (cons (car l)) (cdr (cdr l))))` line: you call `cons` with only one argument, but you also have only one form in this `cond` clause, whereas it should have a test and at least one expression behind.

Answer (score -1):

The list-sum function can be optimized. First it is possible to join the two `(list-sum (cdr lst))` expressions and it is possible to reduce the three `(car lst)` expressions to one:

```
(define (list-sum lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ (let ((l (car lst)))
           (if (pair? l)
               (list-sum l)
               l))
         (list-sum (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: That hardly counts as optimization, it changes neither the speed nor the space usage of the function... Also, God kills a kitteh each time you use a first-letter variable.